# .htaccess to redirect all requests to index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess

So I want to set things so that all requests go through index.php.

Some Google searches gave me this mod_rewrite

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(index\.php|public|css|js|robots\.txt) 
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

This works. But, I don't want it to run if I actually hit index.php.
So
I want www.domain/test to be treated as www.domain/index.php/test, which it does.

But if I hit www.domain/index.php/test in the browser, it should do the same thing but it redirects to a home folder somewhere.

Also I read that I wouldn't want this redirect to happen with css, js and robots.

How do I make the rule not do anything for index.php?

Comment: ... didn't you already do that? `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` -- "If the file does not exist..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work;

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|css|js|robots\.txt|test) 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Didn't work. domain/test stopped working altogether (no input file specified), and domain/index.php/test still does the same thing as before.

Comment: if you have a folder name test, then add it to condition, look at my answer again and let me know it doesn't work

Comment: Managed to get it to work with my original one. Turns out the mistake was inside index.php itself. Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: would you mind taking a look at my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77879577/7543162) please?