# Prevent users from accessing files and folders while allowing the application to

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, server

Is it possible to redirect any URLs other than `example.com` (e.g. `example.com/assets/`, `example.com/made-up-filename.ext`, `example.com/includes/`, `example.com/a/random/made/up/path/`, etc), whether or not these directories or files actually exist, back to example.com while still allowing the application to access files that are essential for rendering or executing? In other words, assets are stored in `example.com/assets/...`, but I want to be able to prevent a user from viewing the directory index in the browser's viewport if they visit `example.com/assets/` directly while obviously allowing the application to access it so that the page can be rendered. Additionally, I want to prevent the user from typing some random path or file into the address bar by redirecting every instance of this back to example.com too. Below is some code that works well, except for the fact that it allows the user to access `example.com/assets/` or `example.com/assets/asset.ext` and view the index or asset in the browser for example. Is achieving both of these goals simultaneously even possible?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # Exclude existing files and directories from redirection
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  # Redirect any attempt to access anything else to the root
  RewriteRule ^ / [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

I know the code below is explicitly allowing this to occur, but I am at a loss of how to achieve this.

```
  # Exclude existing files and directories from redirection
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Below is my current code, which seems to do the trick.

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
  Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  # Redirect any attempt to access anything other than the root to the root
  RewriteRule !^$ / [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: an explanation for the vote to close would be appreciated...

Comment: For a web server there is no real difference between a request coming from another page on your website or someone directly entering that URL in browser. There is only one weak way of doing this is by checking HTTP Referrer but keep in mind that it can be mimicked by someone.

Comment: @anubhava hm... so there is no way to hide the index of the directory if somebody punches the URL directly into the address bar without breaking the website's functionality? :...( (thanks for taking a look btw)

Comment: As I suggested it can be done only based on HTTP Referrer string check

Comment: Moreover you should always disable directory listing, even your app will not need it

Comment: "to hide the index of the directory" - This is a different question and is resolved by placing `Options -Indexes` at the top of the `.htaccess` file. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932641/deny-directory-listing-with-htaccess - I doubt that your application needs to access the directory directly anyway? By "application" I assume you mean the client-side HTML/JavaScript (as opposed to the server-side application)? The server-side application should not be making HTTP requests (to itself at least) so is not subject to restrictions imposed in `.htaccess`.

Comment: @anubhava i have no idea how i overlooked the 2nd half of your comment. i never even knew you could disable directory listing, but i will look into that now! by disable it, do you mean password protect the directory or somehow disable the display of the index?

Comment: @MrWhite beautiful. i think thats what anubhava was referencing. i will look into that as soon as im finished this other errand. ty!

Comment: @MrWhite just read the rest of your comment. by "application," i simply meant any files that were essential to running the website. for example, the `.css` file has to access `/assets/fonts/font.woff2`, whereas, in response to user activity, a `.js` file in `/` posts a fetch request to a `.php` file also in `public_html/` that includes yet another php file, `public_html/includes/file.php` to connect to the database. theres htaccess statements that prevent the "application" from accessing other parts of the directory, thus displaying an `index.php` without any rendering whatsoever

Comment: @MrWhite the Q&A that you linked is exactly what i wanted to do. placing the `IfModule mod_negotiation` block above the `IfModule mod_rewrite` block did the trick. do you know if it is possible to also serve a 403 if a user attempts to access `public_html/includes/connect_database.php` while still permitting the "application" to access it?

Comment: `.js, .css, .png` etc are all client-side code/asset and as a best practice these files should be cached in the client side browsers for longer duration to serve your pages faster. If a `.css` is including a `.php` file then a web request for that `.php` file will look same on the web server whether a user types it directly in a browser or it is included in another `.js/.css` file. At this stage, we again go back to same HTTP Referrer point I posted above.

Comment: @anubhava ill add my current htacess code to my Q. its strange cuz if i navigate to example.com/includes/connect_database.php -- it loads a blank page

Comment: `RewriteRule !^$ / [L,R=301]` can be just `RewriteRule . / [L,R=301]` and it won't affect `example.com/includes/connect_database.php` since your rule is only redirecting non-files and non-directories.

Comment: @anubhava the reason i switched from `^ /` to `!^$` is because i was told `!^$` wont redirect root to root, whereas `^ /` supposedly does still redirect root to root. can you verify this? i am assuming `. /` also redirects the root to root since `.` is any character, right?

Comment: A `.` won't match root/landing page since it requires at least one character to match which is same as `!^$`

Comment: @anubhava doesnt `.` equal any character? do u know where id find the documentation for this specific implementation of regex?

Comment: I already wrote that a dot matches any single character

Comment: @anubhava then how does it not match a single character of root? `!^$` makes sense because it matches no characters between the start and end